# How to avoid infinite times API hitting by calling API service method in Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, api, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have one component with API service method

**TS**

```
     showAcknowledgement() {
this.noticeService.getNotice(ConstUrls.NoticeManagement.GetUserNotice).subscribe((data: any) => {
              data.data.filter((res: any) => {
              if (data.isSuccessful === true) {
                this.noticeText = res.noticeText
                this.noticeAttachment = res.noticeAttachement,
                this.noticeCode = res.noticeCode
              }
            })
            });
          }
```

I need to call this service method to Interceptor:

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((resp) => {
        if (resp instanceof HttpResponse && resp.body.isNotificationAvailable) {
          this.showAcknowledgement();
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

API is hitting infinite times [image]

Comment: Where and how is the function `showAcknowledgement()` called?

Comment: Its called in app component

Comment: `intercept()` gets called for every http request and since you're making a new http request from within `intercept()` that results in an infinite recursion. So, why are you trying to call `showAcknowledgement()` from the interceptor in the first line? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: In showAcknowledgement method, I have API which hits all the screen when isNotificationAvailable is true

Comment: Still not clear why you're using an interceptor... An interceptor containes logic to be executed for every single http call made by your application. Is really that your use case? If that's _really_ the case you need to exclude the GetUserNotice API from firing the interceptor. Otherwise you obviously end up with infinite recursion: call API -> intercept -> call API -> intercept...

Comment: I am using interceptor because to check all the API whether "isNotificationAvailable"  property is true or False. Your are correct. I need to go with other logic. Plz give me some suggestion

Comment: Hard to give you any advice without knowing better your specific use case. It sounds quite weird to me that every single API in your application might return a `isNotificatonAvailable` property... As I said, an option would be to exclude GetUserNotice from the interceptor: it's the API you call when `isNotificatonAvailable` is true, it doesn't make sense to check the condition on _that_ API. You could check the `url` on the `HttpRequest` object and call `showAcknowledgement` only if `isNotificatonAvailable` is true and the url is not GetUserNotice. That should solve the recursion at least.